# How does then() feed its parameters

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Trying to wrap my head around Javascript promises. I am experimenting with the Q library.  I have some code that outputs what I expect, but I'm not sure how it is working:

```
'require strict';

var Q = require("q");

function getFirst(){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var first = 5;
    console.log("getting first: " + first);
    deferred.resolve(first);
    return deferred.promise;
}

function addSecond(first){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var second = 10;
    console.log("adding second: " + second);
    var result = first + second;
    deferred.resolve(result);
    return deferred.promise;
}

function printResult(result) {
    console.log("result is + " + result);
}

getFirst()
.then(addSecond)
.then(printResult);
```

Running this in Node i get:

```
getting first: 5
adding second: 10
result is + 15
```

What I'm confused about is how do addSecond and printResult get their parameters when they are eventually called?  How did '5' magically make it into addSecond?  What if addSecond needed a whole bunch of parameters?

Thanks for shedding light on this.

Comment: `then` gives to its function whatever the previous promise gets fed by `resolve`. If you want `addSecond` to be called like `addSecond(2, 3)`, you need to do `deferred.resolve(2, 3)` in the promise it follows.

Comment: The simple answer is "that's the way promises work". In more detail, a promise delivers a result by passing it to its "then" methods' callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addSecond` gets its parameters from:

```
deferred.resolve(first);
```

so the value is `5`.

`printResult` gets its parameters from:

```
var result = first + second;
deferred.resolve(result);
```

so the value is `first + second`.

---

You can experiment with this. Pass the values you want to pass to your function into `.resolve()` and see it changing. Basically, `.resolve` is acting like a pointer to the function you pass to `.then()`.

Answer (score 1):

Any parameter that you add to deferred.resolve([params]) is sent to the deferred function or DoneCallback (function indicated in .then(function)).
It does accept multiple parameters (https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/).

Answer (score 0):

When you call a promise it waits until underlying function "resolves", then call next function passing resolved value as parameter (this value is resolved on `deferred.resolve(first)`). Then whether the new function returns a promise the cycle is repeated, otherwise just call next function passing returned value.

If you need to pass more than one parameter, you can return a array.

Great presentation of promises:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0):

Your addSecond code can be simplified to

```
function addSecond(first){
    var second = 10;
    console.log("adding second: " + second);
    return first + second;
}
```